# Solr: How to pass a sequence of terms to a field as single query string

Tags: solr

I have a field type defined as follows:

```
<fieldType name="text_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="2"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="2"/>
</analyzer>
```

I want to query a field (named passage_body) of this type as follows(for example):

> q=passage_body:(the term of DPGC Convener)

The problem is while indexing the text in this field, the analyzer works just fine. But, while querying, if I set the debugQuery parameter to true, I can see that the field is not analysed as intended(Shingles are not formed). This is the debug output:

```
<str name="rawquerystring">passage_body:(the term of dpgc convener)</str><str name="querystring">passage_body:(the term of dpgc convener)</str><str name="parsedquery">passage_body:term passage_body:dpgc passage_body:convener</str><str name="parsedquery_toString">passage_body:term passage_body:dpgc passage_body:convener</str>
```

When I analyse the query in Solr admin, the output is as expected.
I even tried setting the "sow" query parameter of Standard Query Parser to false, but even that didn't work.

In short, this is my final query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mnitdocs/select?q=passage_body:(the term of dpgc convene)&sow=false&debugQuery=true
```

In a nutshell, I want to match shingles of query to shingles of passage_body.
Please suggest ways. Other suggestions are also welcome as I am new to Solr.

I am using Solr 5.3.1.

Comment: just a guess but have you tried url encoding the whole q= payload: passage_body%3A(the%20term%20of%20dpgc%20convene)

Comment: Can you post an example of how you want the query string parsed?

Comment: I want the query string passed as "the term of DPGC Convener". I am using quotes to denote that it is a single string, but not a phrase. Now the analyser should process this string (tokenizing, making shingles).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. Setting the query parameter "sow" to false works fine. Its just that it is available only in latest version of solr(6.5.0). So I switched to Solr 6.5.0.